# How to add a date three weeks from now using DateTime C#

Tags: c#, datetime

I am trying to add a due date for a library app.  I got today's date & time using

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
```

Any suggestions on how to add three weeks to that at the time it is being checked out?

Comment: Is your work week 5 days long or do you want to add full 7 day week?

Answer (score 4):

```
var threeWeeksFromToday = DateTime.Today.AddDays(3*7);
```

Comment: @Ralf just editing it yourself would also be acceptable, probably more so than the comment trail as presented. It's fixed now; the comments can be removed